# How can I get the data-value of an HTML button in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="favorites" data- 
   value="{{[i]}}">Favorites</button>
</form>
```

I have this button in Html, I want to obtain the variable "i" which is contained in the "data-value", to use it in Python, I'm using Flask also, thanks!.

Comment: Do you mean you want the Flask code to get that value when the form is submitted?  I'm not sure this is possible, as `data-value` is not a standard form element attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server (Flask/Python) won't have access to the data-value attribute when you submit the form. It's not part of the data that gets sent to the server.

You might try adding a "hidden" form element, which will send a key/value pair to the server without displaying anything to the user:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="value" value="{{[i]}}">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="favorites" data-value="{{[i]}}">Favorites</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, you can retain the data-value attribute on the button, but it's not doing anything so only keep it if you're using it in Javascript somehow.

Also note that `{{[i]}}` will output the string representation of an array with one value, `i`. So the value you will get on the server is `"[5]"` if i is 5 for instance. If you want an actual array on the server, there are other ways to do that.